# Comma between c# , javascript, and jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a  little problem with a comma in jquery ,

```
vmaxy2 = double.Parse(maxy2.Text , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// C# part : value  : 0,3
```

Javascript part :

```
var maxim2 = <%= vmaxy2 %>  ;
```

Jquery part :

```
 $.plot($("#chart"), data, { yaxes: [{ min: 0},{min : 0 , position: "right",tickFormatter: Pourcentage , tickDecimals: 2 , max : maxim2  }],
                                       xaxis: { mode : 'time', minTickSize: [1, "day"] }
                                        });
```

But the result is like that :

```
3.00
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: try -> `var maxim2 = "<%= vmaxy2 %>";`, in javascript a comma is not a valid delimiter for numbers.

Comment: so please what do you suggest ??

Comment: @ adeneo , its not the problem

Comment: @ Felipe it's the result , I need 0.3 in the max of the chart , not 3.00

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough context here. What does the generated HTML look like, for example?

Comment: I found the solution : 

// code behind  c# part 

      string vmaxy2 = maxy2.Text; 

and Javascript part 

       var maxim2 = <%= vmaxy2 %>  ;
      ... {min : 0 , position: "right", tickDecimals: 2 , max : parseFloat( maxim2 )}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
// C# part : value  : 0,3
```

You're just looking at the result of the default `ToString()` handling. If you're propagating this to Javascript, then chances are you're not using the invariant culture for *that* part.

I suspect that when you say "Javascript part" you actually mean "Razor in ASP.NET MVC" part, in which case you could use:

```
var maxim2 = <%= vmaxy2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>;
```

That way you'll end up with Javascript of:

```
var maxim2 = 0.3;
```

... which is what you want.

Comment: I mean javascript in asp.net
And i tried that in the code behind, but it didnt work

Comment: @user2572055: "it didnt work" is never enough detail. What happened? What did the generated JS look like? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: I found the solution : 
I did like you said but i made some changes so : 
string vmaxy2 = maxy2.Text;
after that : 

 max : parseFloat( maxim2 )

Comment: @user2572055: I wouldn't do that - you've parsed it in the C# already; you shouldn't have to parse it again in the Javascript.

Comment: i changed what i did in the c#, i just put the value of textbox : "maxy2" into string variable " vmaxy2" that's all 
after that i parse it in the javascript.

Comment: @user2572055: But my point is that it would be a better idea to parse it in C# - aside from anything else, that means that you *know* the value is going to be a valid double within the Javascript.

Comment: I see, y're 100% right, i will do it

Answer (score 0):

The `InvariantCulture` treats a comma as a separator. Like this: `1,000.75`. You should parse `0.3`, not `0,3`.

Either that, or not use the `InvariantCulture`, but the appropriate one for that value.

Comment: Isn't the comma there because of localization?

Comment: Yes. Different cultures treat `.` and `,` differently. In some, the former is the decimal separator, the latter is the group separator. In some, it is the other way round. Which means, one thousand in some cultures is `1,000.00`, in others it is `1.000,00`